# How to sum all percentage values in a string?

Tags: c#

I am reading a field where the strings in this field are dynamic. Meaning the texts change from time to time but there are always values in the text. I would like to find values in this string and sum them up. There is a percentage behind the values and sometimes spaces beftween the number and the percentage symbol and I would like to find all the values from the string and sum them up. I already tried the following but this does not work

```
    var values = inputString.Split(' ')
                      .Where(s => s.Contains('%'))
                      .Select(s => s.Trim('%'));

    var result = values.Sum(val => val.ToDecimal());
```

Just as an example, here is how the input string looks like

```
- the element contains 1% and also 2% of the something
- Only 1% of A
- Only 5 % of A
- the element contains 1% of A, 2% of B and also 2 % of C ...
```

I want to sum up only the values attached to the % symbol.

Any Ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: _"I already tried the following but this does not work"_ : Could you be more explicit about what "doesn't work" mean? Error, with some message? Difference between expected output and actual output?

Comment: Could you give the expected output for your example? As you say "values attached to the %", does that mean that the `2 %` is _not_ attached because there is a space in between?

Comment: The exptected output for the first input string is 3, 1 for the second and 5 for the last. I tested this on dotnetFiddle but I get  `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]` . Yes you are right. 2 is attached but sometimes there is a space between the % and the value. sorry for the confusion. I would like to get these values and sum them up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a regular expression for solving this problem:

```
private int CalculateSum(string text)
{
    Match match = new Regex(@"\d+\s*%").Match(text);

    int sum = 0;

    while (match.Success)
    {
        sum += int.Parse(match.Value.Substring(0, match.Value.Length - 1).Trim());
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

If you want handle the double values too, you can use the next function:

```
double CalculateDoubleSum(string text)
{
    Match match = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)?\s*%").Match(text);

    double sum = 0;

    while (match.Success)
    {
        sum += double.Parse(match.Value.Substring(0, match.Value.Length - 1).Trim());
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well for ints. How can I change this for maybe decimals or doubles?

Comment: Answer is good. With some tweaks on the regex, you can remove the need of the manual remove (hint: use capture groups)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try to get the position of the '%' in the string and the extract the two chars before that position as a string? If one of the chars that you get is a blank space, then you could just delete it from the string.

Comment: that would work for the examples given, but not if there is `12 %` or `3.5%`, which seem plausible inputs as per OP's comments.

Comment: True, I did not think about that.

Comment: True Pac0.  And also @Kapitani's answer above would work for integers but not for decimals

Comment: I have just added a new version, it will work for doubles too.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to scan for everything after a space until you get to either a space or '%'. If you get a space, then just skip that and go on. If you get a '%' take everything between the space and the '%'.